Static declaration for function in C
I would like to know if this is a good practice:
Making functions static in a C project if they are only used within that file and not by external references? Is this something I should do systematically?

It is definitely a good idea to make functions (and variables) static. If they need to be accessed from another source file, you should have a header that declares them, and you should include the header in both the source file that defines them and in every source file that uses them.  See questions such as Should I use #include in headers? and Self-sufficient headers in C/C++? for further discussion.

Yes, it is good practice to declare a function with static if it is not needed outside its translation unit.
It is generally good practice to declare things with the most restrictive visibility needed for them to work. That is a general principle that applies to declaring variables just within the scope throughout they are used, for example.
This is because the lack of need for any greater visibility means there is no benefit to greater visibility, and greater visibility would mean more exposure to errors, such as confusion of names between different contexts.

Ok good, thank you
